# Custom resources in Android (different vocabularies)

Tags: java, android, resources

I have a problem in Android java where I want to have different vocabularies in different languages. 
The app is used by the military and police force in Germany and Sweden.
Of course the germans want the app in german and the swedes want it in Swedish and that is of course taken care of by putting string resources under res/values-de/strings.xml and res/values-sv/strings.xml and is selected by different settings in the Android device (see [Resource handling](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)).
But my problem is that the police-force uses a different vocabulary than the military force wich I want to reflect in some way in the resources. 
Is there any way to have different vocabulary-resource that i can set in app f.ex by having a res/values-de-mil/strings.xml or in any ohther simple way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. 
An option would be to set the preferences of the user in shared preferences (you could ask that when the user open the app for the first time) and store if it's a policeman or a military.

Then you could use reflection to load your strings resources.

```
<string name="string_policeMan">Word for a policeman</string>
<string name="string_military">Word for a military</string>
```

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isPoliceMan = shared.getBoolean(policeMan, false);

int resId;
if(isPoliceMan)
   resId = R.string.class.getField("string_policeMan").getInt(null);
else 
   resId = R.string.class.getField("string_military").getInt(null);

 String field = context.getResources().getString(resId);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a way to do this, namely by (**ab**)using quantity strings. Just for academical purposes I'll give you a proof of concept below, but as a warning up front: know that this approach does *not* generalize to *any* locale. For German and Swedish, however, you should be fine.

For the theory behind quantity strings (or plurals, as they're usually referred to as Android resources) please have a [read here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals). It also has an explanation for why the approach outlined below does not generalize to any locale. I'm going to assume that will all make sense, so let's fast forward to the proof of concept.

**values-de/plurals.xml**

```
<resources>
    <plurals name="hello_im_in_the">
        <item quantity="one">Hallo, ich bin in der Armee.</item>
        <item quantity="other">Hallo, ich bin auf der Polizei.</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

**values-sv/plurals.xml**

```
<resources>
    <plurals name="hello_im_in_the">
        <item quantity="one">Hej, jag är på militären.</item>
        <item quantity="other">Hej, jag är på polisen.</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

Let's use above resources in an activity with four `TextView`s: two for every locale, and one for every 'force' (police force vs. military that is).

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.res_activity_layout);

    int policeForceQuantity = 0;
    int militaryQuantity = 1;

    TextView militaryTextViewDe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.military_de);
    TextView policeForceTextViewDe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.police_force_de);

    Configuration config = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
    config.locale = Locale.GERMAN;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    String militaryText = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.hello_im_in_the, militaryQuantity);
    String policeForceText = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.hello_im_in_the, policeForceQuantity);
    militaryTextViewDe.setText(militaryText);
    policeForceTextViewDe.setText(policeForceText);

    TextView militaryTextViewSv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.military_sv);
    TextView policeForceTextViewSv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.police_force_sv);

    config = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
    config.locale = new Locale("sv");
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    militaryText = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.hello_im_in_the, militaryQuantity);
    policeForceText = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.hello_im_in_the, policeForceQuantity);
    militaryTextViewSv.setText(militaryText);
    policeForceTextViewSv.setText(policeForceText);
}
```

All above does is use a quantity of `1` to 'select' military phrases, and any other value (`0` in this example) for phrases specific to the polic force. For the sake of the example, I'm simply changing the locale at runtime so we get to see the results side by side, and without actually having to go into the device's locale settings.

**Result:**

[image]

In other words, this shows we were able to successfully take advantage of Android's locale system, and use a predefined quantity to select the military phrase or police force phrase for displaying.

Not pretty, and definitely not what quantity strings were intended for, but it will get the job done in your specific use case.

Comment: Well it is an interesting solution but as you say a bit dirty. The problem is that the app might get translated to other languages, but anyway I might be able to use this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know its not possible to have res/values-de-mil as android system does not know who the user is. You can do this approach have 2 sets of strings.
For e.g.you have a

`<string name="Name">...</string>`

make it as

`<string name="mil_Name">...</string>`

`<string name="cop_Name">...</string>`

Now if u know that the user is military then `getResources().getString(R.string.mil_Name);`

Comment: Also looks like a viable idea, thanks alot for the prompt answer